# How to install Windows 8 Developer Preview on VirtualBox in Ubuntu?

Tags: virtualbox, windows-8-preview

I have downloaded the Windows 8 developer preview ISO and I'm trying to get it running on VirtualBox 4.1 in Ubuntu 11.04 64-bit. Short story: it doesn't work.

I see a message "Loading files..." followed by a title screen that says "Windows Developer Preview." Then I get an error with some funny boxes and in between it some text that appears to say '... restart your computer...' followed by some error codes.

My machine is a dual-core Intel Centrino running at 1.6GHz with 2GB of RAM. I have assigned the VM 1GB of system RAM, 32MB of VRAM and enabled PAE/NX and 2D acceleration.

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Additional information:**

- My CPU does not support hardware virtualization.
- The download is not corrupt since it boots in the actual computer without issue.

Comment: `My CPU does not support hardware virtualization.` - then you can't.

Comment: Check below guides to install Windows 8 developer preview on VirtualBox & VMware workstation 8: - [Install Windows 8 Developer Preview on VirtualBox 4.1](http://www.mytricks.in/2011/09/guide-install-windows-8-developer.html)
- [Installing Windows Server Developer Preview on VirtualBox 4.1
](http://www.mytricks.in/2011/09/guide-installing-windows-server.html)
- [Installing Windows 8 Developer Preview on VMware Workstation 8](http://www.mytricks.in/2011/09/guide-installing-windows-8-developer.html)

Comment: Try assigning some of those 32 gigabytes of video RAM to actual RAM. Just kidding, you don't have hardware virtualisation.

Comment: @todda: Ooops :) That's a typo.

Answer (score 6):

- Select Windows 7 as option in VirtualBox
- Enable VT-x and Nesting Paging
- Enable PAE/NX
- Enable IO APIC
- Enable 3D Acceleration, you can enable 2D Acceleration also

> Source and step by step guide here : http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-install-windows-8-virtualbox

Comment: I didn't enable 3D acceleration... trying that.

Comment: That didn't work either.

Comment: It's a challenge to get a developer build running on bare metal on certain types of hardware, this combined with Ubuntu as your host OS, may just be a battle not worth fighting.

Comment: @Nick Josevski: what is behind "Ubuntu as host OS"?

Answer (score 2):

[This article](http://www.sysprobs.com/guide-install-windows-8-virtualbox) will step you through installation on VirtualBox.

Comment: I followed those steps too, worked fine.

Comment: I don't have hardware virtualization.

Comment: @George Then I believe you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

VirtualBox seems to have more success loading the Windows 8 image than either VMware's or Microsoft's offerings. Grab a VirtualBox if you haven't already (why not? It's free!) and create a new system, using "Other Windows" as the OS type.

I don't know what the minimum required specs are for Windows 8, but I gave the VM 4096MB of RAM and a 60GB hard drive, which should be plenty. Choose to create a new start-up hard disk using the VDI file format.

More detailed instructions on these steps can be found here:

> http://www.hypervhd.com/hyper-v-install-and-upgrade-f24/install-windows-8-in-vbox-t1726.html